# Receive all values for input[] in array form in jQuery to send to PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am busy getting values on a form using jQuery to send to my PHP script. Well, most of my checkboxes have a name in the form of `name="input[]"` and so when I alert the value that gets returned in my form's `submit()` handler, it only returns the value of the first checkbox with that name. How can I return the values in array form?

Here is my code:

```
$("form.enquiry").submit(function () {
    // general enquiry variables
    var name = "";
    var email = "";
    var enquiry = "";

    // quote enquiry variables
    var company = "";
    var address = "";
    var cellphone = "";
    var quote_package = "";
    var quote_items = "";

    // data to be sent to sendEmail.php
    var data = "";

    if ($(this).find("input[name='enquiry_type_chk']:checked").val() == "General") {
        name = $(this).find("input[name='general_name_txt']").val();
        email = $(this).find("input[name='general_email_txt']").val();
        enquiry = $(this).find("textarea[name='general_enquiry_txt']").val();

        data = "name_txt="+name+"&email_txt="+email+"&enquiry_txt="+enquiry;
    }

    if ($(this).find("input[name='enquiry_type_chk']:checked").val() == "Quote") {
        name = $(this).find("input[name='quote_name_txt']").val();
        email = $(this).find("input[name='quote_email_txt']").val();
        company = $(this).find("input[name='quote_company_txt']").val();
        address = $(this).find("input[name='quote_address_txt']").val();
        cellphone = $(this).find("input[name='quote_cell_txt']").val();
        quote_package = $(this).find("input[name='quote_package_chk[]']").val();
        quote_items = $(this).find("input[name='quote_item_chk[]']").val();

        data = "name_txt="+name+"&email_txt="+email+"&company_txt="+company+"&address_txt="+address+"&cellphone_txt="+cellphone+"&quote_package_txt="+quote_package+"&quote_items_txt="+quote_items;

        alert(data);
    }


    return false;
});
```

and part of my form:

```
...
<td><input type="checkbox" name="quote_item_chk[]"  id="quote_package_chk" value="Login member area" class="power toolbox quote_item_chk" />
<label for="quote_package_chk" class="nostyle item power toolbox">Login/member area</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="quote_item_chk[]" class="quote_item_chk basic power toolbox" id="quote_package_chk" value="Photo video gallery" />
<label for="quote_package_chk" class="nostyle item basic power toolbox">Photo and/or video gallery</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="quote_item_chk[]"  id="quote_package_chk4" class="quote_item_chk" value="Portfolio" />
<label for="quote_package_chk4" class="nostyle item">Portfolio (gallery + custom descr.)</label></td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use serialize for creating string like data. or use serializeArray() to fetch all form elements as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over the returned elements (instead of calling `val()` on the group, which only operates on the first), but it would be easier to stop reinventing the wheel and just use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't think of using `serialize()`.